# How to merge multiindex column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge static data with time varying data.

First dataframe

```
a_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A","B","C"],["1","2"]])
a_index = pd.date_range("20100101","20110101",freq="BM")
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=a_columns,index=a_index)#A
```

Second dataframe

```
b_columns = ["3","4","5"]
b_index = ["A","B","C"]
b = pd.DataFrame(columns=b_columns,index=b_index)
```

How do i join these two? My desired dataframe has the form as A but with additional columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then create `df` by [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) - for concat need `Datetimeindex`, so new index was from first value of index of `a`.

Last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
#added some data - 2
a_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A","B","C"],["1","2"]])
a_index = pd.date_range("20100101","20110101",freq="BM")
a = pd.DataFrame(2,columns=a_columns,index=a_index)#A

#added some data - 1
b_columns = ["3","4","5"]
b_index = ["A","B","C"]
b = pd.DataFrame(1,columns=b_columns,index=b_index)

c = b.stack().to_frame(a.index[0]).T
print (c)
            A        B        C      
            3  4  5  3  4  5  3  4  5
2010-01-29  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1

d = pd.concat([a,c], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (d)
            A                    B                    C                  
            1  2    3    4    5  1  2    3    4    5  1  2    3    4    5
2010-01-29  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-02-26  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-03-31  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-04-30  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-05-31  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-06-30  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-07-30  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-08-31  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-09-30  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-10-29  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-11-30  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-12-31  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Last if need replace `NaN`s only in added columns by first row:

```
d[c.columns] = d[c.columns].ffill()
print (d)
            A                    B                    C                  
            1  2    3    4    5  1  2    3    4    5  1  2    3    4    5
2010-01-29  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-02-26  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-03-31  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-04-30  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-05-31  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-06-30  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-07-30  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-08-31  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-09-30  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-10-29  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-11-30  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010-12-31  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Similar solution with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
c = b.stack().to_frame(a.index[0]).T.reindex(a.index, method='ffill')
print (c)
            A        B        C      
            3  4  5  3  4  5  3  4  5
2010-01-29  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-02-26  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-03-31  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-04-30  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-05-31  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-06-30  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-07-30  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-08-31  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-09-30  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-10-29  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-11-30  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2010-12-31  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1

d = pd.concat([a,c], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (d)
            A              B              C            
            1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5
2010-01-29  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-02-26  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-03-31  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-04-30  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-05-31  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-06-30  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-07-30  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-08-31  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-09-30  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-10-29  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-11-30  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
2010-12-31  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
```